# "unexpected type" error when comparing enum values

Tags: java, enums, compiler-errors, equals-operator

Most people I've seen with this problem were using `=` where they needed `==`. What's causing my problem here?

```
com\callmeyer\jopp\FieldCoordinator.java:303: unexpected type
required: class, package
found   : variable
                    if (event.getType() == event.Type.INSERT) {
                                           ^
```

The enum definition and accessor:

```
public class DataLayoutEvent {
    public static enum Type { INSERT, DELETE, RENAME, MOVE, RESIZE }

    private Type type = null;

    public Type getType() {
        return type;
    }

    ...
}
```

and the method where the error occurs:

```
public void layoutChanged(DataLayoutEvent event) {
    if (event.getType() == event.Type.INSERT) {
        fieldAdded(event.getField(), event.getToIndex());
    }

    ...
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use static access instead of instance access:

```
if (event.getType() == DataLayoutEvent.Type.INSERT) {
```

You can (but shouldn't) use instance access for static members (methods and fields), but not for inner types.

Comment: Huh, I thought I'd used the non-static shortcut before successfully. Maybe that only works for static fields, not nested classes and enums.

Answer (score 3):

It should just be:

```
// From within DataLayoutEvent
if (event.getType() == Type.INSERT) {
```

or

```
// From other classes
if (event.getType() == DataLayoutEvent.Type.INSERT) {
```

The `Type` part is the name of a type - it can't be qualified by a variable value (`event`). You could import `DataLayoutEvent.Type` if you wanted to use the first form from elsewhere, by the way.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to refer to `Type` differently:

```
if (event.getType() == DataLayoutEvent.Type.INSERT) { ... }
```